# ¿Cómo agrupar filas por fecha en un marco de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe `news_df` con títulos de artículos y fechas y quiero agrupar los artículos que fueron escrito el mismo día sobre la misma línea.

```
    name
date    
2019-01-17 14:41:00 Forte hausse de l'indice Philly Fed en janvier
2019-01-17 14:36:00 Baisse des inscriptions hebdomadaires au chômage
2019-01-16 22:30:00 Wall Street finit en hausse, Goldman Sachs et ...
2019-01-16 16:14:00 Wall Street, soutenue par les résultats de ban...
2019-01-16 14:36:00 Baisse de 1% des prix à l'import en décembre
...
```

Intente lo siguiente:

```
news_df.resample('D', on='name')
```

Pero me da:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-bdfd57eadc21> in <module>
----> 1 news_df.resample('D', on='name')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base, on, level)
   7108                      axis=axis, kind=kind, loffset=loffset,
   7109                      convention=convention,
-> 7110                      base=base, key=on, level=level)
   7111         return _maybe_process_deprecations(r,
   7112                                            how=how,

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in resample(obj, kind, **kwds)
       1146     """ create a TimeGrouper and return our resampler """
       1147     tg = TimeGrouper(**kwds)
    -> 1148     return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
       1149 
       1150 

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in _get_resampler(self, obj, kind)
       1274         raise TypeError("Only valid with DatetimeIndex, "
       1275                         "TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, "
    -> 1276                         "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
       1277 
       1278     def _get_grouper(self, obj, validate=True):

    TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Answer (score 0):

voy a intentar contestarte yo a esta también. Aquí el problema que veo es que `Pandas` no está cogiendo el `Index` de la tabla bien. Esto es porque la fecha (`date`) está metida en la tabla como un `str`. Por lo que lo toma como un `Index` normal. Y lo necesitas como `DatetimeIndex`, `PeriodIndex`, o `TimedeltaIndex` para poder hacer el `resample` [pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

**Solución:**

- Debes parsear el `str` de la fecha a un objeto `Datetime`.
- Usar `resample` sobre `date` y sumar los valores.

**Código:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import strptime

page = requests.get(
    'https://www.abcbourse.com/marches/news_valeur.aspx?p=1&s=DJIAx')

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
actualites_ws = soup.find(class_='inner_left2')
spans_date_article = actualites_ws.find_all('span', class_="lh24")

# Variable para crear DataFrame
data = {'date': [], 'name': []}
for article in spans_date_article:
    data['name'].append(article.find('a').text)
    data['date'].append(
        pd.to_datetime(
            article.find('span', class_="mr5").text, format="%d/%m/%y %M:%S"))

# Crear DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Agrupar
df = df.resample('D', on='date').sum()

print(df)
```

Prueba a ver si te funciona. ˆˆ